# primeNG multiselect dropdown retains checkbox value after removing and then adding again same value dynamically

Tags: angular, primeng

I am populating primeNG multiselect dropdown with respect to value selected in another dropdown.
code for Dropdown 1 in .html file:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="destinations" [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'12em'}" [showToggleAll]="false" [filter]="false" (onChange)="ondestinationSelect($event)" defaultLabel="Select Destination(s)" maxSelectedLabels="0" selectedItemsLabel="{0} Destination(s) Selected">
  <ng-template let-destination>
    <span>{{destination.label}}</span>
  </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
```

code for dropdown 1 in .ts file :

```
ondestinationSelect(event) {
    let destinationIdArray = <FormArray>this.addteammateform.get('destinationsresponsiblefor');    
    let destinationId = new FormControl();

    if(event.value.length > destinationIdArray.length) {
      this.usermanagementService.get_residences(event.itemValue).subscribe(response => {
        if(response.length > 0) {
          for(let residenceIndex of response) {
            let residencePush = {label : residenceIndex.residence_name, value:{id:residenceIndex.id, destination_id : residenceIndex.destination_id}};
            this.residences.push(residencePush);
          }
        }    
      });
      destinationId.setValue(event.itemValue.id);
      destinationIdArray.push(destinationId);
    }
    else {
      let residenceCount = this.residences.length;
      let deleteResidenceArray : any = [];


      for(let i=residenceCount - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        if(this.residences[i].value.destination_id == event.itemValue) {
          this.residences.splice(i, 1)
        }
      }

      let destinationIndex = destinationIdArray.controls.indexOf(event.itemValue.id); 
      destinationIdArray.removeAt(destinationIndex);
    }
  }
```

code for dropdown 2 in .html file :

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="residences" [optionLabel]="label" [showToggleAll]="false" [filter]="false" showHeader="false" defaultLabel="Select Residence(s)" maxSelectedLabels="0" selectedItemsLabel="{0} Residence(s) Selected" [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'12em'}">
  <ng-template let-residence>
    <div style="font-size:14px;float:right;margin-top:4px">{{residence.label}}</div>
  </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
```

Drop down one is also primeNG multiseltect dropdown and is prepopulated when page is loaded.

1. Check off any option(s) in **dropdown 1**. It populates **dropdown 2**
   with values corresponding to **dropdown 1**.
2. Check off any option(s)
       in **dropdown 2**. It shows "x" items selected.
3. Now, uncheck option(s) from **dropdown 1**.
4. Values in **dropdown 2** is removed  but "x" items
   selected remains same and not getting updated.
5. Now, again check off value(s) in dropdown 1 (same value(s) as in
   step 1).
6. **Dropdown 2** is populated with value(s) corresponding to **dropdown 1**  but this time values are already checked (value(s) that was selected in step 2).

check boxes in drop down 2 retains value after removing and adding again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which changedetection strategy do you use?

Comment: Alexander, I didn't understand your question.